# Visual Studio 2015: MSVSMON.exe does not appear to be running on the remote computer for blank Cordova project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

just starting to look at the Cordova tools for Visual studio.

Creating a blank Cordova probject, I am able to run (F5 debug), for Android and IOS (emulators), and also x86 windows, but for either Any CPU or x64 I get the following error..

`The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer.`

So I have seen mentioned elsewhere that VS (32 bit) needs to run the above for 64 bit debugging. I have no problems running and debugging a classic desktop WPF.

I have tried disabling both my firewall (Zone Alarm) and any antivirus (Avast), but made no difference.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem could be here (or how to diagnose)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. I use the same applications as you do, Zone Alarm and Avast. If I try to debug and get that error, disabling or stopping the programs do not help. You need to close VS and restart it with the offending apps already disabled, then you'll be able to continue.

I stumbled across this question because I am looking for a way to keep from doing this.